# Liquibase Type Mapping MySQL & SQL Server

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-cli

From command line I let liquibase run in the version 4.19.0.

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml update
```

where `update.xml` is a bundle of changelogs:

```
<databaseChangeLog ...
    <include file="changelog_1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changelog_2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The first run ends with an error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Data type definition contains unparseable embedded information: `${dbtype.varchar}(20)`

So far as I understand the `${dbtype.varchar}` comes from my company and in Java code I see a replacement.

My question is for MySQL `${dbtype.varchar}` should be replaced with `VARCHAR` and for SQL Server with `nvarchar`.

Is there an easy way to tell liquibase to replace this placeholder with MySQL values?

In the `liquibase.properties` I tell liquibase that it should be done for MySQL.

```
driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
classpath: /home/markus/drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar
```

EDIT:
I found inside the Liquibase [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/home.html?Highlight=command%20line) how I can do it with properties from outside.

liquibase --changeLogFile=batch_changelogs.xml update -Ddbtype.bigint=BIGINT -Ddbtype.ubigint='BIGINT UNSIGNED'

It's not exaclty what I'm looking for but at the momement is comfortable to use.

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it inside the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/connections/creating-config-properties.html)

In liquibase.properties I can add with the parameter.

```
parameter.dbtype.bigint=BIGINT 
parameter.dbtype.ubigint='BIGINT UNSIGNED'
```

Solved for MySql. For MSSQL I will generate a new property file and change by exeuction.